# Capturing this required to access member functions?

Tags: lambda, c++11

I am using a `std::for_each` loop on a local variable of a member function of a class. I would like to call another member function of that same class from the lambda in the for_each. Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
void some_class::another_function()
{
    cout << "error";
}
void some_class::some_function( function<bool(const int)> &f)
{
    vector<int> local_variable = {0,0,0,1,1,3,5,43};

    std::for_each( local_variable.begin(), local_variable.end(),
            [&f](const int item)
            {
                if( !f(item) )
                    another_function();
            }
}
```

GCC 4.6 is telling me that `this` isn't captured (so I should do that).  Is that the best solution? Or should I only capture those functions I need (but that could be messy for larger constructs)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC is right: to call member functions on `this` from inside a lambda, you must capture `this`. If the member function does not depend on the data members, make it `static`, and then you do not need to capture `this`.

You cannot capture "functions", only local variables (including parameters and `this`, but not specific data members).

Comment: In lieu of explicitly capturing `this`, he could just use [&] to capture everything by reference. It's a local function using `std::for_each`; there's no reason not to capture everything by reference and potentially optimize the compiler-generated functor into a simple function pointer.

Comment: Only lambdas that capture **nothing** can be reduced to a function pointer. However, regardless of the capture set, the lambda will be a class with an inline function call operator, and will likely be inlined directly into the `std::for_each` loop. Capturing everything with `[&]` is certainly less typing than explicitly capturing each variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture `this` if you want to call member functions, and that's pretty much the end of it.